# -moz-inline-box vs -moz-inline-stack

Tags: css, firefox, properties

What's the difference between Firefox's `-moz-inline-box` and `-moz-inline-stack` proprietary display values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display

> **-moz-inline-box** ~ (no detail given)
>
> **-moz-inline-stack** ~ Child elements, including inline-block, block, and -moz-inline-stack are laid out atop one another.

Comment: `-moz-inline-box` works like `inline-block`, I used it for early versions of Firefox that didn't supported `inline-block`.

Comment: -moz-inline-stack is no longer documented on that page.